# salvar mais que um input em lista

Tags: python

Estou tendo problemas com a criação de uma lista aceitando todos os inputs. Eu preciso criar uma lista contendo todos os nomes e apostas dos usuários, mas o meu código só está guardando na lista o último input de nome e aposta, os primeiros inputs não estão sendo salvos, por exemplo:

what is your name?
carol

What is your bid?
$ 7

Are They any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'
yes

what is your name?
manoel

What is your bid?
$ 6

Are They any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no'
no

A lista que tenho no final:
['manoel','6']

ou seja, o primeiro input desaparece.
Meu código:

````
while others:
  apostas = []
  nome = input("what is your name?\n")
  aposta = input("What is your bid? \n $ ")
  outros = input ("Are They any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no' \n")
  for n in aposta:
    apostas.append (nome) 
    apostas.append(aposta) 
  clear()
  if outros == "no":
    others = False
    print("end")
print(apostas)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testei seu código em minha máquina e encontrei alguns pontos. Quando você declara a lista vazia dentro do `loop while` ela sempre é resetada quando volta pra primeira linha. fiz algumas modificações e rodou bem aqui

```
apostas = []
while True:  
    apostas.append(input("what is your name?\n")) 
    apostas.append(input("What is your bid? \n $ "))
    outros = input ("Are They any other bidders? Type 'yes' or 'no' \n")
    if outros == "no":
        others = False
        print("end")
        break
    else:
        continue
print(apostas)
```

Você pode também colocar o `input` dentro do `append` e tirar o `for loop`, o `clear()` não precisa pq o `input` vai sobrescrever as variáveis.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Deu super certo! era isso mesmo que eu queria! Muito obrigada :)

Comment: @carolis disponha!